# Next(‘profile’) inside router.beforeEach gives error, need help to figure it out

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to add access controls in my app. The issue is the next(‘profile’) gives me an error saying:

```
[vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation:
Invalid object
```

I tried changing the line from next(‘profile’) to next() and it works without any issues. It gives error for next(‘login’) as well. But the first next(‘login’) works without any issues. Can somebody please help me?

My code is:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // Checking if user has verified the mobile number using firebase
  const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser
  // Checking if the requested path has meta requiresAuth
  var isUserLoggedIn = false
  const loginTokenExistsFlag = CookieManager.checkIfLoginTokenExists()
  if (loginTokenExistsFlag && currentUser) {
    isUserLoggedIn = true
  }
  var isUserActivated = false
  const profileDetails = CookieManager.getProfileDetails()
  if (profileDetails != null) {
    if (
      profileDetails.profile_user_description == null &&
      profileDetails.profile_name == null
    ) {
      isUserActivated = false
    }
  }
  if (isUserLoggedIn == false) {
    next('login')
  } else if (isUserLoggedIn == true && isUserActivated == false) {
    next('profile')
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

Route definition

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  linkActiveClass: 'active',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: '/login'
    },
    {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/profile',
      name: 'profile',
      component: Profile,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      redirect: '/login'
    }
  ]
})
export default router
```

---

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: `'login'` and `'profile'` should probably have a leading forward-slash (ie `'/profile'`), assuming they're meant to be paths. What do your route definitions look like?

Comment: I tried that and didn't make any difference. `if (isUserLoggedIn == false) {
    next('login') }` works. Anyway added the route definition. Thanks.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the full error, including stack trace? Since your routes are named, I would use `next({ name: 'profile' })` and `next({ name: 'login' })`

Comment: Ah, move your `*` route to the end of the route list. From the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#catch-all-404-not-found-route) ~ _"When using asterisk routes, make sure to correctly order your routes so that asterisk ones are at the end"_

Comment: @Phil Moved it, but it did nothing. :( I get the same error. Heres the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/nik8is

Comment: Please update the code in your question. Have you restarted your dev-server? Which is line 114 of `src/router.js`?

Comment: Done, and yes I have restarted the server. 114 is `next('profile')`. Whatever I give there except `next()` shows the same error.

Comment: All guards except afterEach are “asynchronous”. Could you please try to console whether all are executing one after or another(means line by line)

Comment: What happened to using real paths (ie `'/profile'`) or by name (ie `{ name: 'profile' }`)? The string `'profile'` is not valid

Comment: @Phil I did that as well, still not working. I tried both giving `'/profile'` and `{name: 'profile'}` without luck. Anyway, I thought I will write it from scratch with a different logic and it worked. I don't understand why the code in the question didn't work .

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why its not working, I figured I will write it from scratch in some other way and see if that solves the problem. It solved the issue indeed. I am not going to mark this as answer because I still don't know what caused the issue in the question. But here is the working code if someone wants to know.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/views/Home.vue'
import Login from '@/views/Login.vue'
import Profile from '@/views/Profile.vue'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import CookieManager from '@/managers/CookieManager.js'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  linkActiveClass: 'active',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: '/home'
    },
    {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        requiresActivation: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/profile',
      name: 'profile',
      component: Profile,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: Login
    }
  ]
})
export default router

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // Checking if user has verified the mobile number using firebase
  const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser
  var isUserLoggedIn = false
  const loginTokenExistsFlag = CookieManager.checkIfLoginTokenExists()
  if (loginTokenExistsFlag && currentUser) {
    isUserLoggedIn = true
  }
  var isUserActivated = false
  const profileDetails = CookieManager.getProfileDetails()
  if (profileDetails != null) {
    if (
      profileDetails.profile_user_description == null &&
      profileDetails.profile_name == null
    ) {
      isUserActivated = false
    }
  }

  // Checking if the requested path has meta requiresAuth
  var requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)
  var requiresActivation = to.matched.some(
    record => record.meta.requiresActivation
  )

  if (requiresAuth && requiresActivation) {
    if (isUserLoggedIn && isUserActivated) {
      next()
    } else if (requiresAuth && !isUserActivated) {
      next('/profile')
    } else {
      next('/login')
    }
  } else if (requiresAuth && !requiresActivation) {
    next()
  } else if (!requiresAuth) {
    if (isUserLoggedIn) {
      next('/home')
    } else {
      next()
    }
  }
})
```